# Why formating don't occure after rng.Clear?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making small excel to reduce the amount of work at my job.
I decided that because of frequent data refreshing using VB would be the best resolution to constant formatting and clearing cells. I haven't touch VB in 5 years and I don`t see why this isn't working.

The code should work I checked it as different buttons but after some copying and pasting, conditional formatting isn't working.

```
Set rng = Range("B1:B15")

    rng.Clear

    'Formating Data with color to Value
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type =   xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 8109667
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

The code should empty cells B1 to B15 and format them to change colours based on value. Its only part of colour formatting I didn't want to put all 24 lines of code.

Comment: Why did you switch from `rng` to `Selection` midway through the code? Unless `Selection` happens to be `B1:B15`, this probably isn't what you intended.

Comment: Yea i just saw that :D i was using macro maker to ease work 

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's unclear from your questions, but there is subtle difference between `Clear` and `ClearContents`

   - `Range.Clear` clears all **formulas** and **formatting** inside the `Range` object
   - `Range.CearContents` clears the content of the cell (value) but leave formatting intact

So make sure you're using the right one, perhaps even both if necessary, also it's a good idea to [avoid `Select` altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). In your case `Selection`is valid only if the user selects a specific `Range`inside the Worksheet.

2. It seems instead you might want to be applying the format to your `rng` object instead

   ```
   rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3 'and so on..
   ```